# Setting SecurityExit property on Websphere MQ connection

Tags: ibm-mq

In order to authenticate using security keys from a Java\Scala client, I understand that the following property must be set on the MQ connection:

```
Key:securityExit
Value: bctoolsj.wsmqtools.exits.BCPKIJCExit
```

I am using `IBM Websphere MQ Explorer (version 7.5.0.2)`.
Where in this tool can one set the property?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Value: bctoolsj.wsmqtools.exits.BCPKIJCExit

I presume your MQAdmin has setup the server-side security exit that matches this client-side security exit?

> I am using IBM Websphere MQ Explorer (version 7.5.0.2). Where in this tool can one set the property?

Did you follow the instructions in the [MQ Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q020420_.htm)?

i.e. Right click on the queue manager, select Connection Details then Properties.  Click on security exit and input the information.

Comment: Queue manager -> Connection Details ->Properties: Only properties under the category 'General' can be set, and these do not include securityExit. What needs to be done to add securityExit as a property? Thanks

Comment: You do know the difference between a local queue manager and a remote queue manager?  Security exits are ONLY used for remote queue managers.  From your description, it tells me that you are looking at the properties of a local queue manager.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Are you saying that if the queue is setup locally, the certificates (dll's) can be used for authentication without the securityExit property being set?

Comment: There is no network Comms between Explorer and Queue Manager if you have it configured locally. Without network, you are not using SSL/TLS and so certificates are not relevant.